# COUNT Multiple tables with relationships and users

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a group of tables in SQL Server that I need to count on with specific counting criteria for each table, the problem I'm having that I need to group this by users, which are contained in one table and are mapped to the tables I need to count on via a relationship table.

This is the relationship table

```
 Relationship    User    Work Item
 Analyst         1       IR1
 Analyst         2       IR2
 Analyst         2       IR3
 Analyst         1       IR4
 User            3       IR1
 Analyst         1       SR2
 Analyst         1       SR3
 Analyst         2       SR4
```

This is the IR table (the SR table is identical)

```
 ID     Status
 IR1    Active
 IR2    Active
 IR3    Closed
 IR4    Active
```

This is the user table

```
 User     Name
 1        Dave
 2        Jim
 3        Karl
```

What I need is a table like below counting only the active items

```
 Name   IR Count  SR Count
 Dave   2         2
 Jim    1         1
```

All I seem to be able to do currently is count all of the users regardless of status, I think this may be due to the left joins. I basically had:

```
 Select u.name,
 count (ir),
 count (sr) from user u
 Inner join relationship r on r.user=u.user and r.relationship = 'Analyst'
 Left Join IR on r.workitem=ir.id and ir.Status = 'Active'
 Left Join SR on r.workitem=sr.id and sr.Status = 'Active'
 Group by u.name
```

I have simplified the above as much as possible. This is the actual query:

```
 SELECT 
 u.DisplayName as Analyst, 
 u.BaseManagedEntityId as AUsername,
 COUNT(distinct i.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) AS 'Active Incidents',
 COUNT(distinct sr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) as 'Active Service Requests',
 COUNT(distinct cr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) as 'Active Change Requests',
 COUNT(distinct ma.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) as 'Active Manual Activities'
 FROM MTV_System$Domain$User u 
 INNER JOIN RelationshipView r ON r.TargetEntityId = u.BaseManagedEntityId AND r.RelationshipTypeId = '15E577A3-6BF9-6713-4EAC-BA5A5B7C4722'  AND  r.IsDeleted ='0'
 LEFT JOIN  MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident i ON r.SourceEntityId = i.BaseManagedEntityId AND (i.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED != '2B8830B6-59F0-F574-9C2A-F4B4682F1681' AND i.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED != 'BD0AE7C4-3315-2EB3-7933-82DFC482DBAF')
 LEFT JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$ServiceRequest sr ON r.SourceEntityId = SR.BaseManagedEntityId AND (sr.Status_6DBB4A46_48F2_4D89_CBF6_215182E99E0F = '72B55E17-1C7D-B34C-53AE-F61F8732E425' OR sr.Status_6DBB4A46_48F2_4D89_CBF6_215182E99E0F = '59393F48-D85F-FA6D-2EBE-DCFF395D7ED1' OR sr.Status_6DBB4A46_48F2_4D89_CBF6_215182E99E0F = '05306BF5-A6B9-B5AD-326B-BA4E9724BF37')
 LEFT JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$ChangeRequest cr on r.SourceEntityId = cr.BaseManagedEntityId AND (cr.Status_72C1BC70_443C_C96F_A624_A94F1C857138 = '6D6C64DD-07AC-AAF5-F812-6A7CCEB5154D' or cr.Status_72C1BC70_443C_C96F_A624_A94F1C857138 = 'DD6B0870-BCEA-1520-993D-9F1337E39D4D')
 LEFT JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$Activity$ManualActivity MA on r.SourceEntityId = ma.BaseManagedEntityId AND (ma.Status_8895EC8D_2CBF_0D9D_E8EC_524DEFA00014 = '11FC3CEF-15E5-BCA4-DEE0-9C1155EC8D83' OR ma.Status_8895EC8D_2CBF_0D9D_E8EC_524DEFA00014 = 'D544258F-24DA-1CF3-C230-B057AAA66BED')

 GROUP BY u.DisplayName,u.BaseManagedEntityId
 Order by u.DisplayName
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem?  If you clean up column names in your example and add DISTINCT in your counts you will get your desired result.  Which is the method your more complex query is using.  So what behavior/count issue are you specifically trying to fix?

Comment: The distinct in the counts wasn't working. It was returning users with a relationship of analyst into the results table that didn't have any active items which met the filter criteria. If a user has a relationship but the work item is not active then they shouldn't be returned.

Comment: that is because of the LEFT JOINs.  If you constrain that with testing in the where statement to make sure at least one of the values in your left joins is not null then that shouldn't happen.  However it would still be possible for example to have IR count = 0 and SR Count > 0 if you want only when IR & SR are not 0 then simply make them inner joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your over simplification seems to have lost your what appears to be your issue from some of your comments.  Using left joins would include any of the users even if they don't have a count of one of your other tables.  However if you want your result set to only include usres that have at least 1 Incident and/or 1 Request and/or 1 Change Request. Etc. you can either filter the aggretation you are doing after the fact to remove when Incidents + Requests + ... = 0.  Or you can filter them out by adding a WHERE statement that says WHEN NOT all of those other tables are null which is the same as OR IS NOT NULL...

```
 SELECT 
 u.DisplayName as Analyst, 
 u.BaseManagedEntityId as AUsername,
 COUNT(distinct i.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) AS 'Active Incidents',
 COUNT(distinct sr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) as 'Active Service Requests',
 COUNT(distinct cr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) as 'Active Change Requests',
 COUNT(distinct ma.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) as 'Active Manual Activities'
 FROM
    MTV_System$Domain$User u 
    INNER JOIN RelationshipView r
    ON r.TargetEntityId = u.BaseManagedEntityId
    AND r.RelationshipTypeId = '15E577A3-6BF9-6713-4EAC-BA5A5B7C4722' 
    AND  r.IsDeleted ='0'
    LEFT JOIN  MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident i
    ON r.SourceEntityId = i.BaseManagedEntityId
    AND i.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED NOT IN ('2B8830B6-59F0-F574-9C2A-F4B4682F1681','BD0AE7C4-3315-2EB3-7933-82DFC482DBAF')
    LEFT JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$ServiceRequest sr
    ON r.SourceEntityId = SR.BaseManagedEntityId
    AND sr.Status_6DBB4A46_48F2_4D89_CBF6_215182E99E0F IN ('72B55E17-1C7D-B34C-53AE-F61F8732E425','59393F48-D85F-FA6D-2EBE-DCFF395D7ED1','05306BF5-A6B9-B5AD-326B-BA4E9724BF37')
    LEFT JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$ChangeRequest cr
    ON r.SourceEntityId = cr.BaseManagedEntityId
    AND cr.Status_72C1BC70_443C_C96F_A624_A94F1C857138 IN ('6D6C64DD-07AC-AAF5-F812-6A7CCEB5154D','DD6B0870-BCEA-1520-993D-9F1337E39D4D')
    LEFT JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$Activity$ManualActivity MA
    ON r.SourceEntityId = ma.BaseManagedEntityId
    AND ma.Status_8895EC8D_2CBF_0D9D_E8EC_524DEFA00014 IN ('11FC3CEF-15E5-BCA4-DEE0-9C1155EC8D83','D544258F-24DA-1CF3-C230-B057AAA66BED')
WHERE
    i.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C IS NOT NULL
    OR sr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C IS NOT NULL
    OR cr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C IS NOT NULL
    OR ma.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.DisplayName,u.BaseManagedEntityId
 Order by u.DisplayName
```

Also note the user of IN and NOT IN in the join conditions instead of OR all of the time.

Comment: That's much better and thanks for the help with the IN/NOT IN, I hadn't come across those before. You were also right in the simplication. Many thanks for your help

Comment: @Alex Glad it works for you, please consider accepting my answer so that people understand your question has been answered and reputation points are awarded.  Thanks. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `count()`.  Instead, you want `count(distinct)`:

```
Select u.name,
       count(distinct ir),
       count(distinct sr)
from user u
. . .
```

This generates a Cartesian product between the `ir` and `sr` values.  If you have largish numbers in each group, then aggregating before the `join` is a better approach.

Comment: Hmmm that doesn't seem to work either, it's still returning users in the count where the status isn't active

Comment: Got it, just needed to put the filters as a where after the joins rather than on the joins

Comment: @Alex if you place a condition on a table that is the RIGHT side of a LEFT JOIN in the where clause it becomes an INNER JOIN which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below script .

```
SELECT u.name
  ,SUM(t1.[IR Count]) [IR Count]
  ,SUM(t2.[SR Count]) [SR Count]
FROM #user u
 INNER JOIN #relationship r on r.[user]=u.[user]and r.relationship = 'Analyst'
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ID) [IR Count]
               FROM #IR ir WHERE r.workitem=ir.id and ir.Status = 'Active') t1
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ID) [SR Count]
               FROM #SR sr WHERE r.workitem=sr.id and sr.Status = 'Active')t2
GROUP BY u.name
```

**OUTPUT** :

[image]

SR Count in your sample output is wrong ,if the SR table is same as that of IR table (Status of the SR3 is closed for the user 'dave' so that will be ignored.) .

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        U.UserID,
        U.Name,
        CASE WHEN R.WorkItem LIKE 'IR%' THEN R.WorkItem ELSE '' END AS IRCode,
        CASE WHEN R.WorkItem LIKE 'SR%' THEN R.WorkItem ELSE '' END AS SRCode
    FROM @tblUser U
    INNER JOIN @tblRelationship R ON U.UserId=R.UserId
)
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(CASE IRCode WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS 'IR Count',
    SUM(CASE SRCode WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS 'SR Count'
FROM T 
WHERE 
(
    (T.IRCode=''
    OR
    T.SRCode='')
    AND
    (
        T.IRCode IN (SELECT ID FROM @tblIR WHERE Status='Active')
        OR
        T.SRCode IN (SELECT ID FROM @tblSR WHERE Status='Active')
    )
)
GROUP BY T.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with that seems to work based off the actual table

```
 SELECT 
 u.DisplayName as Analyst, 
 u.BaseManagedEntityId as AUsername,
 COUNT(distinct i.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) AS 'Active Incidents',
 COUNT(distinct sr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) as 'Active Service Requests',
 COUNT(distinct cr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) as 'Active Change Requests',
 COUNT(distinct ma.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) as 'Active Manual Activities'
 FROM MTV_System$Domain$User u 
  LEFT JOIN RelationshipView r ON r.TargetEntityId = u.BaseManagedEntityId AND r.RelationshipTypeId = '15E577A3-6BF9-6713-4EAC-BA5A5B7C4722'  AND  r.IsDeleted ='0'
  LEFT JOIN  MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident i ON r.SourceEntityId = i.BaseManagedEntityId
  LEFT JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$ServiceRequest sr ON r.SourceEntityId = SR.BaseManagedEntityId
  LEFT JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$ChangeRequest cr on r.SourceEntityId = cr.BaseManagedEntityId
 LEFT JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$Activity$ManualActivity MA on r.SourceEntityId = ma.BaseManagedEntityId 
 Where (i.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED != '2B8830B6-59F0-F574-9C2A-F4B4682F1681' AND i.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED != 'BD0AE7C4-3315-2EB3-7933-82DFC482DBAF')
 OR (sr.Status_6DBB4A46_48F2_4D89_CBF6_215182E99E0F = '72B55E17-1C7D-B34C-53AE-F61F8732E425' OR sr.Status_6DBB4A46_48F2_4D89_CBF6_215182E99E0F = '59393F48-D85F-FA6D-2EBE-DCFF395D7ED1' OR sr.Status_6DBB4A46_48F2_4D89_CBF6_215182E99E0F = '05306BF5-A6B9-B5AD-326B-BA4E9724BF37')
 OR (cr.Status_72C1BC70_443C_C96F_A624_A94F1C857138 = '6D6C64DD-07AC-AAF5-F812-6A7CCEB5154D' or cr.Status_72C1BC70_443C_C96F_A624_A94F1C857138 = 'DD6B0870-BCEA-1520-993D-9F1337E39D4D')
 OR (ma.Status_8895EC8D_2CBF_0D9D_E8EC_524DEFA00014 = '11FC3CEF-15E5-BCA4-DEE0-9C1155EC8D83' OR ma.Status_8895EC8D_2CBF_0D9D_E8EC_524DEFA00014 = 'D544258F-24DA-1CF3-C230-B057AAA66BED')
 GROUP BY u.DisplayName,u.BaseManagedEntityId
 Order by u.DisplayName
```

Comment: hmmm that makes some of your tables an inner join and others are still LEFT Joins and if any of those status columns can contain a NULL then you have even larger issues

Comment: The status columns cannot contain a NULL value, it's forbidden by the system

Comment: that's good.  But think of this if i.Status.... is = to one of the ones you don't want but that same record matches on of the sr.statuses then you will get a count of the wrong i status.  The conditions should stay in your joins.  One thing you can do is get rid of aggregation and look at the record set to see if it is how and what you want before aggregating.  In this case I do not believe it will be.